# Relation between spectral radius and norms

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying convergence of iterative methods for determined linear systems of equations, and came across the following:

"For any square matrix **B**, the following conditions are equivalent:

$$\rho(B)<1$$
$\|B\|<1$, for some subordinate matrix norm"

But, I created a test case which has $ B=\begin{bmatrix}0  & 0.3077\\3.0000  &       0\end{bmatrix}$

B has $\lambda_1=0.9608, \lambda_2=-0.9608 $

but $\|B\|_2 =3$

Where is my inconsistency ?

Both calculations were done in MatLab

Comment: Obviously, you need another matrix norm. To see that a norm reduction is possible, consider something like the operator norm for the vector norm $\|x\|= \max(0.3·|x_1|,3·|x_2|)$.

Comment: So the result guarantees the existence of **some** norm which is bounded , but not that **all** norms will be ?

Comment: Yes. For every $ε>0$ there is a vector norm so that in its associated operatornorm $\|B\|\le ρ(B)+ε$. Which implies here that there are operator norms with $\|B\|\le\frac{ρ(B)+1}2<1$.